# Why can't my friend access the new Airship map in Among Us?

Tags: among-us

My friend is having trouble finding the new “Airship” map in Among Us. They went to the menu where the maps are at the top, but still cannot find the map. The message announcing the map popped up, but it isn’t in any menus. Is anyone else experiencing this, and if so, how do you fix it?

Comment: What platform are they playing on?

Comment: They are on a laptop.

Comment: The changelog is loaded from the server, meaning your friend probably hasn't updated despite the message

Comment: "they got it via steam" *moving information up to the top, quote from the poster*

Comment: What happened to every answer on this question?